# hg diff ignore ^M

Tags: android-studio, mercurial, eol

I am using Android Studio 2.2.3 & Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.0.1), running on MacOS Sierra 10.12.3.

I am using Hg command base client. `hg diff` shows:

[image]

Here is my ~/.hgrc

```
 [extensions]
 purge=
 color =
 pager =

 [pager]
 pager = LESS='FRSXQ' less
 quiet = True
 attend = outgoing,incoming,diff,status,log,qdiff,blame,annotate,pdiff,glog
```

Any config I should add to avoid showing `^M` in diff? In Android Studio or Mercurial config? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends a bit on what you want:

a) Is it only that **you** do not want to see whitspace / eol character changes so that you can better review a diff? Then use the appropriate flag to the diff command: `hg diff -b` shows the diff while ignoreing whitespace changes including EOL.

b) If you generally have that problem and want to have some repository-side aid in messing with the EOL characters: make use of the EOL extension. However, the much more advisable approach is to use properly configured editors and maybe repository hook which rejects files with the wrong EOL characters.

Comment: I can take your suggestion in (a) to ignore whitespace changes, but I am concern about (b) too. We have 2 developers working on same repository. I am using Android Studio on MacOS, another teammate uses Android Studio on Windows. Any experience with Android Studio setting here, so it shouldn't conflict between MacOS & Windows? Thanks!

Comment: FYI `hg diff -b` still shows `^M` at end of line. These lines of code are newly added, not modifying any existing line though.

Comment: Possibly due to my `pager extension` config? Comment out `pager extension` in .hgrc fix my issue, no more showing `^M` at EOL.

Comment: I don't think so... I've pager extension active as well:https://paste.openttdcoop.org/pwoydfwkd But yes, they still show when there are also other differences in the same line. diff -b only ignores changes which are purely whitespace / EOL.

Answer (score 2):

Use the EOL extension. Read carefully https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EolExtension before blindly enabling it.

Comment: I can only emphasise: better don't ignore the changes and instead have your commiters use properly configured editors. If you just want to ignore these whitespace changes during viewing a diff, use `hg diff -b`.